# Identify format of a string (Such as Base64)

Tags: text, encoding

I work with a tool that contains everything within XML inside the database.

Some reports that are stored in the database use a third party tool to load, and store the main data to configure the 'report' definition in what is not a human-readable format.

I'd post it here, but it's some 130,000 bytes.

I have attempted to decode it using popular methods that I assumed it would have been encoded in, such as base64, base 32, etc, but none have been able to decode the string.

Is there a way to identify what encoding a given string has, using a tool available online?

I don't have the benefit of access to the developer that built this functionality, the source code generating this string, or any documentation on it.

To give some context around what I'm trying to do - I need to reverse-engineer how a specific definition in a system is generated, so that it can be modified slightly (manually) in a text editor to support an operation that would otherwise require manually re-creating the report.

I apologize is if this may be the wrong exchange site for this question - I realize it's not specific to a 'programming' issue and I haven't tried to solve it using a programming language. If so - please redirect me to the appropriate place and I'll be happy to ask there instead.

**Update**: The text consists of strictly A-Z, 0-9 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check amongst known encoding formats with [this tool](http://encodingchecker.codeplex.com/)  only if you are sure data is not [encrypted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)

Comment: I stripped out the text that I had into a .txt file, and checked it. It came back unknown. Is there a way that I could tell whether this data was encrypted, or is that asking too much? Haha

Comment: assuming that you're not the one who encrypted the data :D you will have to  learn some [cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis), and even after that , if properly encrypted it can take you ages to decipher the code